# Selecting a Dynamically Created Element Polymer 1.0 Safari

Tags: javascript, safari, polymer, mobile-safari

I am trying to append two child nodes to a carousel in Polymer.  This works fine in Chrome, but I get the following console error in Safari:

> TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating `'this.$$('#' + this.slideId1 + '').appendChild'`)

Is there a way to select a dynamically created node by Id in Safari?

I am currently using `this.$$()` Polymer method.

```
<l2t-paper-slider id="paperSlider" total-slides="{{slides}}"></l2t-paper-slider>

<script>
  Polymer({...
    _appendNode: function() {
      this.$$('#paperSlider').appendChild(this.slide);
      this.$$('#' + this.slideId1 + '').appendChild(this.slideData);
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: You're already querying for the node correctly with `this.$$`. The issue could be that the node is not yet attached to the DOM when you query it. If `_appendNode` is called in the same function that adds the `slideId` node to the DOM, you should defer your query until the next render.

Comment: I see... what design pattern would you use to verify completion of the first append?

Comment: What do you mean by "first append"? The first call to `_appendNode`? Or the first `appendChild` inside of `_appendNode`? What adds the `slideId1` to the DOM?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using:

```
Polymer.dom(this.root).querySelectorAll("paper-card");
```

In your case:

```
Polymer.dom(this.root).querySelectorAll("#paperSlider").appendChild(this.slide);
```

Remember that appendChild expects a node so you might need to create one first

```
var mypaperSlider = Polymer.dom(this.root).querySelector('#paperSlider');
var slide = document.createElement('paper-slide');
Polymer.dom(this.root).querySelectorAll("#paperSlider").appendChild(slide);
```